# Google analytics - follow a single users path?

Tags: google-analytics

How can i track a single users path through the webpage with Google Analytics?
I am not interested in who that user is, only what path the user went.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a unique value to a [Visitor-level Custom Variable](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) when a user visits the site. Then you can filter/segment based on the value that you want to examine to narrow down paths by individual. It's not entirely clear whether or not this violates Google's terms, though. You're not technically tracking an individual, you're just relating the actions of various anonymous users.

Comment: If i set a CV to visitor level and generate a unique VisitorID for that user, is that enought to track what pages that visitor browses on every visit or do i need to use page/session scope to do that?

Comment: I am aware of the Google therms, i will filter out all individual data and only keep company specific(on networkLocation)

Comment: You need it at the visitor level so it tracks the same unique ID on every action the visitor takes, whether it's a pageview, an event, an exit, etc. If you were to set it to page level, you would need to define the Custom Variable value on every pageview.

Comment: I have built a testpage with some code generating a unique cookie value.. now i just have to wait some time to get the data into GA =) Ill get back when i see what the results are.

Comment: Now i have got some data to work with, have tried to figure out how to see the chronological order of the pagesview generated by that specific user and i think i need a bit more detailed help =)

Comment: Well.. depending on the exact info you'd like... you can create a segment that includes "Custom Variable (Value 1)" containing the ID you'd like to examine, apply the segment, then click on "Audience" > "Visitors Flow" to get the chronological flow of pageviews that the user followed. Or you can create a custom report with the first level Dimension Drilldown set to Custom Variable (Value 1) and add any additional metrics/dimensions as desired. This would allow you to see all IDs and then additional info about the individuals when you click on them.

Comment: Thank you verry much for your help! The way i solved it was to use a CV on page and set the value to "visitTime", this gives me one single page for each timestamp and i think it will work perfectly when i fetch it with GAPI =)